# How to secure the Salesforce lightning if a malicious user could change the parameter to execute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security

Let's say a site builder could use "community builder" to configure the Salesforce lightning component.
On a login form, they can decide to use "email" or "username" to login in.
However, the login method is executing on the helper.js.
There, the code will read the setting from `isUsingEmailToLogin` attribute. As malicious users, they can always user debugger point to change the value to decide login in using `email` or `username`

Isn't it a big security problem for Salesforce lightning component?

Any thought to avoid this issue on Salesforce lightning component?

```
    var username = component.find("username").get("v.value");
    var password = component.find("password").get("v.value");
    var isUsingEmailToLogin = component.get("v.isUsingEmailToLogin");

    var action = component.get("c.login");
    var startUrl = component.get("v.startUrl");
    startUrl = decodeURIComponent(startUrl);
    action.setParams({userIdent:username, password:password, startUrl:startUrl, useEmailAsIdent: isUsingEmailToLogin});
```

[image]

## Take another out-of-box Salesforce lightning component for example.

Assuming I'm a site admin and configured the `includePassword == true` using the community builder. However, as a bad user, I could even put a debugger point at the `helper.js` and change the value and call the backend call to bypass the `includePassword` option. This code is out-of-box the Salesforce. Isn't it crazy? Just curious how could we enforce this in the backend in a more concrete way.

## Frontend code in the helper.js

```
handleSelfRegister: function (component, event, helpler) {
    var createNewAccount = component.get("v.createNewAccount");
    ...
    var includePassword = component.get("v.includePasswordField");
    ...
    var startUrl = component.get("v.startUrl");
    startUrl = decodeURIComponent(startUrl);

    action.setParams({
        ...
        includePassword: includePassword
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function (a) {

        var rtnValue = a.getReturnValue();
```

## Backend APEX code

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String selfRegister(..., String startUrl, Boolean includePassword) {

    ....

        if (includePassword) {    
            if (!isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {
                return Label.site.passwords_dont_match;
            }
            validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
        }
        else {
            password = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't it a big security problem for Salesforce lightning component?

It shouldn't be. They can just check the box or not anyways. However, in more realistic scenarios, client-side security must be considered compromised by the user. In other words, you must always verify that they are not doing something they shouldn't do.

> Any thought to avoid this issue on Salesforce lightning component?

Always validate your input on the server. For example, we have a component that allows users to upload images. Before that, though, they need to have access to the image uploader and the record for which they're uploading to. Therefore, all of our methods in Apex initially call a security check:

```
@AuraEnabled public static SomeReturnValue someActionHandler(Id recordId) {
  checkSecurity(recordId);
  ...
}
...
public static void checkSecurity(Id recordId) {
  if(!CurrentUser.hasPermission('UploadImages')) {
    throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have access to use this feature.');
  }
  if(recordId == null) {
    throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid parameter to method.');
  }
  SObject[] records = Database.query(
    'select userrecordaccess.HasEditAccess from '+recordId.getSobjectType()+
    ' where Id = :recordId');
  Boolean hasAccess = !records.isEmpty() &&
    recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable() &&
    ((UserRecordAccess)record.getSobject('UserRecordAccess')).HasEditAccess;
  if(!hasAccess) {
    throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have access to upload images to this record.');
  }
}
```

This way, even if someone smart enough to call the server by using the feature, the server itself will reject the request. You should do this for every request to the most reasonable extent possible if you have any concerns about security.

Comment: Hi, I'm so glad for your solution. However, I'm still confused the Salesforce sample code for the selfRegistration which allows a bad user to change the `includePassword` flag. Any thought to avoid this security hole?

Comment: @Dummy Again, if you're concerned about the "security hole," then you can modify this controller to beef up security a bit. I'm curious why you'd be concerned about this particular parameter, though, since the only thing it does is automatically log the user in after user creation.

Comment: Hey. the point is we want our customer to configure the attributes through community builder where you could have a WYSIWYG  feature. However, the attribute seems could be hijacked by a bad user. e.g.: the `includePassword` flag, I could not think of a way to prevent a bad user to change the flag.  I'd like to is there any way that once a site admin config the component attributes and no one can hijack it :(